# Is $Spec(R_p)$ to $Spec(R)$ is an open immersion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $R$ be a ring. $p$ be a prime ideal of $R$ . Let $R\rightarrow R_p$ be the canonical. Consider the map of schemes $Spec(R_p) \rightarrow Spec(R)$. Is it an open immersion. $Spec(R_p)$ is an open set in $Spec(R)$ is clear.

Comment: Re: your last assertion: it is not an open set. For example, let $R = k[t]$ and $P = (t)$. Then $\mathrm{Spec}(R_p) = \{(t),(0)\}$ which is not an open set in $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. (Neither is it a closed set.)

Comment: @Hamou: How is $X:=\mathrm{Spec}(R_p)\setminus\{P\}$ a scheme?

Comment: @Hamou: Your statement is wrong in almost all cases; try a simple example like $R = k[x]$ and $p = (x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{p}=(0)$. (or in fact any other prime ideal.)

Comment: I am looking for an Open immersion which is not finite type. Will this $Spec(S^{-1}R) \rightarrow Spec (R)$ work? I know if we take $ S=\{1,s,s^2, \cdots\}$, then it will become a finite map. Can we choose some other multiplicative system such that $S^{-1}R$ not finitely generated over $R$.

Comment: Then why don't you ask "What is an example of an open immersion which is not of finite type"? A simple example is $\bigcup_i D(x_i) \to \mathrm{Spec}(k[x_1,x_2,\dotsc])$. This is not of finite type since $\bigcup_i D(x_i)$ is not quasi-compact. Notice that open immersions are always locally of finite type.

Comment: Notice that $\mathrm{Spec}(S^{-1} R) \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is usually no open immersion when $S$ is not finitely generated. Take for instance $S=R \setminus \{0\}$ where $R$ is an integral domain which is not a field.

Comment: Yes, I should have asked it directly. I was trying to construct the example on my own.

Comment: @Susobhan: Note that if $X$ is any locally Noetherian scheme (e.g. finite type over a field) then any open immersion into $X$ will be of finite type (because open immersions are always locally of finite type, via the existence of distinguished affine opens in affine schemes, and open subsets of quasi-compact open subsets of locally Noetherian spaces are necessarily quasi-compact).  Thus to get an open immersion that is not finite type, you need to choose a non-locally Noetherian example, which is why Martin's example involves infinitely many variables.

Comment: tracing, thank you! I was not aware of that theorem earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you really mean.

Assume $R$ is an integral domain for simplicity.

If $R_p$ is the localization at the prime ideal $p$, then $R_p$ is a local ring. The image of Spec $R_p$ in Spec $R$ is then precisely the generic point (i.e., zero ideal of $R$) and the points of Spec $R$ specializing to $p$. This is not open in general (consider for instance a Dedekind domain $R$ with infinitely many prime ideals in which case Spec $R_p$ is just two points if $p$ is non-zero).

If you meant to consider an element $p$ in $R$, and the localization $R_p = R[1/p]$ then 
Spec $R[1/p] \to $ Spec $R$ is open. It is usually denoted by $D(p)$ and is a so-called principal open of Spec $R$.

Comment: Note: You are assuming $R$ has dimension 1 here. Otherwise $\mathrm{Spec} R_p$ may have many points (all the prime ideals contained in $p$.)

Comment: A local ring can have infinitely many prime ideals. It has only one *maximal* ideal.

Comment: You guys are right, I was thinking about a one-dimensional $R$. Let me fix that.

Comment: I meant $p$ is a prime ideal in $R$. And now i can see why it is not an open immersion.

Answer (score 1):

As counter-examples have be given, I would like to give a more general explanation. Let $\left( X, \mathscr{O}_X\right)$ be a scheme. You have a canonical morphism $\varphi : \textrm{Spec}\left( \mathscr{O}_{X,x} \right) \rightarrow X$, defined as follows. Let $U$ be an open affine in $X$, containing $x$, and let $A$ be the ring (of global sections of $\mathscr{O}_X$) of (over) $U$. $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$ is then isomorphic to the localisation $A_{x}$ of $A$ at $x$. To the canonical arrow $A\rightarrow A_x$ corresponds therefore a morphism of schemes $\textrm{Spec}\left( \mathscr{O}_{X,x} \right) \rightarrow \textrm{Spec}\left( A \right) = U$, that composed with the open immersion $U\rightarrow X$ give an arrow $\textrm{Spec}\left( \mathscr{O}_{X,x} \right) \rightarrow X$, depending on $U$. If fact it does not depend on $U$. Indeed, for another $U'$, you can find a third $U''$ such that $U'' \subseteq U\cap U'$, so we can assume that $U\subset U'$, and in this case the obvious diagramm invoving $A$, $A'$ and $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$ commutes.

Then $\varphi$ induces an homeomorphism from $\textrm{Spec}\left( \mathscr{O}_{X,x} \right)$ to the subset of $X$ consisting in $y\in X$ such that $x\in\overline{\{ y \}}$. There is therefore really *intuitively* no reason for this set to be open. By the way, the morphisms induced by $\varphi$ on local rings are isomorphism so that $\varphi$ is a monomorphism, even if it is not necessarily an open immersion. On this note, the (set-theoretic) image of $\varphi$ is not generally locally-closed, so it is even not a subscheme.

Comment: I think there are some typos in your second paragraph, e.g. $X$ seems to have switched from being the target to the source of $\varphi$.  Also, the image of $\varphi$ is not th e closure of $x$, but rather the set of points that specialize to $x$.  Also, the image of $\varphi$ is not locally closed *in general*, but could be in particular cases (e.g. if $X$ were actually equal to Spec $\mathcal O_{X,x}$).

Comment: Yeah sorry I know, I'm still editing, but hard from mobile...